# CMake: Unable to link with GMock

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest, googlemock

I'm trying to use GMock in the unit test. But the linkage fails with the next error:

```
In function `testing::internal::linked_ptr_internal::depart()':
/home/user/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-linked_ptr.h:127: undefined reference to `testing::internal::g_linked_ptr_mutex'
In function `testing::internal::linked_ptr_internal::join(testing::internal::linked_ptr_internal const*)':
/home/user/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-linked_ptr.h:110: undefined reference to `testing::internal::g_linked_ptr_mutex'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My Cmake file:

```
target_link_libraries(Test
  ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
  ${GTEST_LIBRARIES}
  log4cplus
  gtest
  gtest_main
  pthread
  "-L/usr/local/lib/libgmock.a" gmock
  "-L/usr/local/lib/libgmock_main.a" gmock_main
  #  gmock
  #  gmock_main
  proto
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:logging_dev>)
```

I tried both using gmock and gmock_main and giving the hardcoded paths.
All other tests that use only GTest compile and run successfully.

What do I do wrong?:)

Comment: What does `GTEST_LIBRARIES` contain? Is that variable populated? Also, [this](https://github.com/google/googletest/issues/1404#issuecomment-359730630) comment seems to indicate you no longer need to link to `gmock_main`. And when providing the *full* path to the linked library, you do not need the `-L` prefix inside `target_link_libraries()`.

Comment: ```GTEST_LIBRARIES``` is empty...
So I've removed ```-L``` and here are the results:

```
/usr/local/lib/libgmock.a(gmock-all.cc.o): In function `testing::Matcher<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&>::Matcher(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
gmock-all.cc:(.text+0x10e4): multiple definition of 
...
```

Comment: If you provide the *full* path to the `libgmock` library, you do not need to link it **again** with `gmock`. You can remove `gmock` from the `target_link_libraries()` call since you have already linked it by providing the full path to the library.

Answer (score 1):

First you must find gtest by

```
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS}/include)
```

Then link gtest *.libs against your test executable file by

```
target_link_libraries(${EXE_NAME} PUBLIC GTest::GTest GTest::Main #other libs)
```